# Redirect first category archive page to normal page

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I am looking for a way to redirect only the first category archive page to a normal page I have created.

I am using this code but this redirects all pages of the category archive. I only want the first page of the category archive to be redirected.

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    if ( is_category( 'news-articles' ) ) {
        $url = site_url( '/news' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: When you say first page, do you mean just the parent category should redirect while sub categories should not - or do you mean `/news-articles/` should redirect while `/news-articles/page/2/` should not?

Comment: I mean /news-articles/ should redirect while /news-articles/page/2/ should not...

Comment: Gotcha, just wanted to make sure because the answers would quite a bit. You just need to check the current `paged` values. I've provided 2 solutions, I'd recommend using `is_paged()`

Comment: ok makes sense.. now I have 8 different categories.. should I create a separate function for each, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: According to the function reference for [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) it takes `$mixed` values, even an array of category names - I've updated the answer to reflect an array

Comment: Actually it will complicate it a bit if the target `$url` is different. Ideally you'd be able to parse the desired URL from the category name in the same way

Comment: I've added a 3rd version if you can't extrapolate the `$url` from the category name. If they were all `'news-articles' => '/news'` and `'book-reviews' => '/book'`, it would make it simpler. If that's not the case, you can just loop through a `$category => $url` array and redirect based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want paginated pages to not redirect, you can check the [`is_paged()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) boolean. It will return true if you're on an archive page greater than page 1 ( the first page of the archive ). So if it returns false, it means we're on the page you want redirected.

```
function my_page_template_redirect(){
    $category_array = array(
        'news-articles',
        'category-2',
        'category-3',
           //...
        'category-8'
    );

    if( is_category( $category_array ) && !is_paged() ){
        $url = site_url( '/news' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Alternatively, you can check the current paged value with [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var), which would look like:

```
function my_page_template_redirect(){
    if( is_category( 'news-articles' ) && get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ){
        $url = site_url( '/news' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

If your desired URL is different for each category, and you can't get the URL from the category name, then something like this may work for your needs without too much overhead:

```
function my_page_template_redirect(){
    $category_array = array(
        'news-articles'  => '/news',
        'category-2'     => '/cat-2',
        'third-category' => '/third_category',
          //...
        'NumberEight'    => '/Eight'
    );

    foreach( $category_array as $category => $url ){
        if( is_category( $category ) && !is_paged() ){
            $url = site_url( $url );

            wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```